# How to refactor $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x - \sin x}$ to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x(-\sin x) + \cos x - \cos x}{1 - \cos x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand that in tri identities, cos(x) = -sin(x), but I don't understand the "+ cos(x) - cos(x)" and "1 - cos(x)" part.

Comment: Hint: De L'Hopital rule

Comment: Perhaps you meant the derivative of cosine, since definitely $\;\cos x\color{red}\neq-\sin x\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a factoring problem.

The L' Hospital rule is applied to the fraction, that is the derivative of the top over the derivative of the bottom is found and if the limit of the resulting fraction is easy to find, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$(x\cos{x}-\sin{x})'=\cos{x}-x\sin{x}-\cos{x},$$
$$(x-\sin{x})'=1-\cos{x}.$$ 
Also, $$x\cos{x}-\sin{x}\rightarrow0$$ and
$$x-\sin{x}\rightarrow0$$ for $x\rightarrow0.$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$(x\cos x)=x'\cos x+x(\cos x)'=\cos x-x\sin x$$

so

$$(x\cos x-\sin x)'=\cos x-x\sin x-\cos x=-x\sin x$$